# Não consigo pegar texto editado no input em uma data-table para fazer update no banco de dados

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

estou tentando fazer um update usando uma data-table, essa data-table é por padrão desabilitada para edição, e em cada linha tem um botão com nome 'Editar' ao clicar no botão a linha e habilitada para edição, e o nome do botão muda para 'Salvar'.
Até aí tudo bem, mas, ao clicar no botão 'Salvar' deveria pegar os valores editados para fazer o update, voltar o nome do botão para 'Editar'e desabilitar novamente a ediçao.

js

```
function botaoEditar(button_edit){
   
   if($(button_edit).parents("tr").find('button span').text() == "Editar"){
      var _row = null;
      _row = $(button_edit).parents("tr");
      var cols = _row.children("td");
      
      $(button_edit).parents("tr").find('input').prop('readonly', false);
      
      alert($("input[name='cabo']").val());

      $(button_edit).parents("tr").find('button').removeClass('btn_editar');
      $(button_edit).parents("tr").find('button').addClass('btn_salvar');  
      $(button_edit).parents("tr").find('button span').text('Salvar');      
   
   } else{
      var _row = null;
       _row = $(button_edit).parents("tr");
       
       $(button_edit).parents("tr").find('input').prop('readonly', true);
     
      
       alert($("input[name='cabo']").val());
       
       $(button_edit).parents("tr").find('button').removeClass('btn_salvar'); 
       $(button_edit).parents("tr").find('button').addClass('btn_editar');
       $(button_edit).parents("tr").find('button span').text('Editar');
   }
```

Obs. o alert() nas duas condições do if  retornam o mesmo valor que vem do banco de dados.

HTML /php

```
foreach($listaRamais as $listRamal){ 
    echo"    
          <tr>
               <td><input typ='text' id='cabo' name='cabo' maxlength='5'style='width:100%;text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' value='".$listRamal['cabo']."'/></td>
               <td><input typ='text' name='par' maxlength='5'style='width:100%;text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' value='".$listRamal['par']."'/></td>
               <td id='ramal'><input typ='text' name='ramal' maxlength='9'style='width:100%;text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' value='".$listRamal['numero_ramal']."'/></td>
               <td><input typ='text' name='setor' maxlength='30' style='width:100%;text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' value='".$listRamal['setor_ramal']."'/></td>
               <td>
                  <button id='btn_edite' type='button' onclick='botaoEditar(this);' class='btn_editar'> 
                     <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'>Editar</span>
                  </button>
               </td>
               <td style='display:none;'>".$listRamal['id_unidade']."</td>                              
          </tr>
      
";                    
}
```

Alguem saberia me dizer como pegar os novos valores digitados?

Comment: Isso `$("input[name='cabo']")` sempre vai retornar esse elemento `<input typ='text' id='cabo' name='cabo' maxlength='5'style='width:100%;text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' value='".$listRamal['cabo']."'/>`

Comment: Mesmo digitando outro texto no input?  eu pensei que ao clicar novamente no botão a função pegaria o novo texto digitado. Qual seria a forma correta para fazer isso?

Comment: Não ele vasculha pela arvore do documento.

Comment: por favor, amigo, teria um exemplo de como eu poderia pegar os dados, digitado?

Comment: Posso até montar um exemplo, mas no momento estou ajudando outra pessoa. Vai ter que aguardar um pouco.

Comment: tudo bem Augusto, pode ser depois, fico no aguardo. obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

obrigado pela ajuda Augusto, analisando seu comentário encontrei meu erro, eu estava setando o elemento fora do objeto "button_edit"
dessa forma:

```
alert($("input[name='cabo']").val());
```

mudei para:

```
alert($(button_edit).parents("tr").find("input[name='cabo']").val());
```

agora esta funcionando perfeitamente!

Comment: 1) Para marcar como resolvido, espere passar o prazo de 24h imposto pelo sistema e [marque a resposta como aceita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), não coloque no título meta-tags(Resolvido) pois confunde os mecanismos de busca e conhecimento gerado aqui fica perdido. 2)Desculpe-me, esqueci da sua pergunta, cheguei a [montar o servidor](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/table#index.php) com o seu código, mas apareceu tanta coisa....